# Chrome command line : Provide custom "Chrome Safe Storage" Keychain password

Tags: google-chrome, keychain

To decrypt Cookies and passwords, Chrome needs the "Chrome Safe Storage" password stored in the Keychain.

I want to be able to run Chrome with a different "Chrome Safe Storage" password. Is there any option to do that? I don't want to change it directly in the Keychain.

-> Something like :

```
chrome --chromesafestorage=password
```

-> Or else a tool to spoof a Keychain password?

(I do that because I have the User Data directory of another user, but if I don't change the chrome Keychain password it won't be able to decrypt some contents when I run `chrome --user-data-dir=dirpath`)